# Making menu item active onclick in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, menuitem

I have side menu bar, where i used ng-repeat to display items in the list.

```
<div class="list-group" style="height:50px">
 <span href="#" class="list-group-item active">
          Inbox
      </span>
      <div ng-repeat="record in inboxlist.Result">
          <a  class='list-group-item'  ng-click="viewDates($index);">{{record.customer_name}}</a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I want to highlight the item on click.I am beginner could someone guide me on how to achive this effect.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) like,

```
ng-class="{selected: $index === selectedIndex}"
```

Your HTML

```
<a  class='list-group-item' ng-click="viewDates($index);" ng-class="{selected: $index === selectedIndex}">{{record.customer_name}}</a>
```

and your `viewDates` function should be like

```
$scope.selectedIndex = null;
$scope.viewDates = function ($index) {
   $scope.selectedIndex = $index;
   //.... your remaining code here 
};
```

Comment: use `active` class instead of `selected` as per OP

Comment: I don't think so, he didn't mention class name (he just said **I want to highlight the item on click**) and you are free to choose class name. So why only `active`?

Answer (score 1):

you can use ng-class to add styles dynamically according to the conditions.

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.inboxlist = {};
$scope.inboxlist.Result = [{"customer_name":"ss"},{"customer_name":"aa"},{"customer_name":"cc"}]

})
```

```css
.change-color{
  color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div class="list-group" style="height:50px">
 <span href="#" class="list-group-item active"   >
          Inbox
      </span> 
      
      <div ng-repeat="record in inboxlist.Result" ng-init="record.check = false">
          <a  class='list-group-item'
          ng-click="record.check = true;viewDates($index);"
          ng-class="{'change-color':record.check}">      {{record.customer_name}} </a>
      </div>
      
  </div>
</div>
```